# How to get the terminating NUL character \x00 into a string?

Tags: c++, string, escaping

How would i get a string with the null character \x00 since \x00 is also the terminating character?

I really do need it for part of my program.

The string I need is "\x00\x00\x00\x00". Is there some special syntax for it? What is it?

Comment: I think you'll need to elaborate a little more what you want to use it for before we'll be able to help you.

Comment: 0 is not a valid display character, and as you know, denotes the end of a string, so how could it ever have a length greater than 0?  Sounds to me like you have a general design issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
std::string str("\0\0\0\0", 4);
```

This constructor tells string to use the 1st 4 characters of the char*, without interpreting any \0 characters as null.

Comment: But then what happens when he tries to use it anywhere else as a normal string? I really think there's a better (and safer) way of achieving what OP wants; if he would only tell us what that is.

Comment: Well, if he tries to use any character array with an embedded null - not just from string - he's going to run into problems, if he doesn't take into account that the nulls are there. But if he keeps the nulls in mind, he'll be fine.  If he wants to convert back to char*, he can use string::data() which doesn't truncate and null terminate. He can use string::iterator to scan, etc.

Answer (score 8):

In C++ the `std::string` class will work while including NUL characters.

However:

- The `c_str()` function will fail.
- The constructors that read a `const char*` will fail.

You would probably be better served by using a `std::vector<char>`.

Answer (score 2):

You're doing it correctly. You just need to ***avoid interpreting*** a null as the ending character.

But then how do you know where it ends? I don't know; you could store the length somewhere instead.

Answer (score 2):

You *can* have a "normal" string which embeds nulls, but at the first null any function that expects a null-terminated string will stop processing it; thus, you need to use counted strings.

C++ `std::string` being a type of counted string, you can use it to carry around these strings. Keep in mind however that you shouldn't convert it back to a C string when using it (i.e. don't use the `c_str()` method), otherwise you will be back to square one.

However, to have more specific suggestions, you should explain a bit better what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: Grammar nit: "C++ `std::string` being a type of ..." not "being C++ ..."

Comment: @Zack: I'm not a native English speaker, I often miss these grammar bits. Anyway, fixed, thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

If it is a std::string you want, you can get any size you want

```
std::string s(10, '\0');
```

gives you a string with 10 nul characters.